# Is there IMAP Mail Retrieval Agent (MRA) solution that caches 'seen' messages?

Tags: email, imap

I wish to find an MRA which will only download mail it hasn't previously downloaded (regardless of IMAP 'seen' flag) and pass them to a Mail Delivery Agent (MDA).

I wish to use a remote IMAP server as a constant e-mail storage which can be accessed by multiple MRAs and MUAs. Thus, if one client marks an email as read (IMAP 'seen' flag) it can still be delivered elsewhere.

Most solutions I have looked into (fetchmail, getmail, etc) allow the options of 'fetch all mail' (not ideal, for obvious reasons) and 'fetch unread mail' (some mails will be lost if read by another MUA). Neither option fits the bill for my use case.

Note: GNU Linux

Comment: OfflineIMAP can synchronize messages this way (uni- or bi-directional); however, it only delivers directly to Maildir folders, not to a MDA.

Comment: There is a tool called [isync](http://isync.sourceforge.net/) (command name `mbsync`, I think), which some people recommend as an [alternative to OfflineIMAP](http://blog.ezyang.com/2012/08/offlineimap-sucks/). I haven't used it though, so can't say for sure if it meets your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OfflineIMAP](http://offlineimap.org/) works this way – it can synchronize entire mail accounts, and remembers which messages it downloaded.

The downside is that OfflineIMAP can only deliver from/to IMAP or Maildir folders, not to a MDA. This is necessary to support bidirectional sync between mailboxes.

Comment: I am currently tinkering with OfflineIMAP, it looks like it may do my job if I run a local IMAP! I can't find any examples of turning it between a uni-directional and bi-directional configuration, I don't even know what the default is; the documentation on this appears weak. Any insight?

Comment: The default is bidirectional sync. But you can set the remote repository to read-only.

Comment: Ah yes, I see it now. This feature was added in OfflineIMAP 6.3.4! I have been playing with the debian squeeze stock OfflineIMAP, which is currently 6.2.0.